# What it's wrong with this discord cog?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to create a Discord bot in Python and I am having issues with my cog file. No errors are logged in the console, however commands don't execute.

The cog file (named `help` in the `cogs` folder):

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def help(cxt, *, text):
        await cxt.send(f'**Help**\nno')
```

The main bot file:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Toh online {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Cetriolino è un mega chaddone!"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if 'cetriolino' in message.content.lower() or 'emme'in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('')
    if 'chad' in message.content.lower() or '' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('')

initial_extensions = ['cogs.help']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        client.load_extension(extension)

client.run('')
```

Comment: You have defined the bot as ```client``` in the main file and ```bot``` in the cog. I have less experience with cogs but I think this is the reason

Comment: `@commands.Cog.listener()` and `async def help(cxt, *, text):` together make no sense at all...

Comment: Dominik mmh can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your cog, first off: The commands need to be in the class, in your case `Help`. You wrote the command in the setup function, which isn't gonna do anything.

Second, you are using a listener for your command when you should be using a command.

Third you need to pass in `self` as the first argument in every function in a class.

Also why are you using `bot` in the cog and `client` in the main file? I would recommend to stick with one thing. Also not sure why you use `cxt`, the convention would be `ctx`.

Try something like this:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Test')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Help(client))
```

Please take your time and read the docs page on cogs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/cogs.html